# integral2 with fun calculated using vector

Tags: matlab

Im new to MATLAB. Want to use integral2 as follows

```
function num = numer(x)
fun=@(p,w) prod((p+1-p).*(1-w).*exp(w.*x.*x/2))
num= integral2(fun ,0,1,0,1)
end
```

I get several errors starting with

```
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in numer>@(p,w)prod(p+(1-w).*exp(w.*x.*x/2)) (line 5)
fun=@(p,w) prod(p+(1-w).*exp(w.*x.*x/2))
```

Can you please tell me what I do wrong. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the help for [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html):

> All input functions must accept arrays as input and operate
>   elementwise. The function Z = FUN(X,Y) must accept arrays X and Y of
>   the same size and return an array of corresponding values.

When `x` was non-scalar, your function `fun` did not do this. By wrapping everything in `prod`, the function always returned a scalar. Assuming that your `prod` is in the right place to begin with and taking advantage of the properties of the exponential, I believe this version will do what you need for vector `x`:

```
x = [0 1];
lx = length(x);
fun = @(p,w)(p+1-p).^lx.*(1-w).^lx.*exp(w).^sum(x.*x/2);
num = integral2(fun,0,1,0,1)
```

Alternatively, `fun = @(p,w)(p+1-p).^lx.*(1-w).^lx.*exp(sum(x.*x/2)).^w;` could be used.

Comment: @user3003027: Did my answer help solve your problem? If it was useful to you, please accept it. Thank you.